# Nativescript screen size on iOS

Tags: ios, css, height, screen, nativescript

I have a tns app that is running fine on Android.

The same app works correctly on IOS too, but the dimensions are altered; i mean, i have big buttons, and some listviews (especially when populated with few elements) do not shrink to the whole screen height; this happens with any ios model on simulator (iphone5, iphone6, etc).

I have already worked on the app.ios.css file, but some of the height: 100% seems not to work...

The app shows perfectly on android. I have searched a lot for this issue, but did not find any answer to a similar problem.

Do you have some idea ?

Nativescript 2.4.3

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a CSS problem. I suggest deleting all css files (backed up of course) and then try running the app. The app won't look the same of course but you can verify the 100% issue. If that seems to be working - you can introduce small snippets of your CSS code back and test. Remember there could be an app.css file also - remove that also.

Comment: post sample CSS that is causing this behaviour under iOS and working on Android.